# The correct way in python to create a class inside another class?

Tags: python, class

I'm learning python and what to know what I'm doing below is correct or is there a better way to write it?

```
class FUNC:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def Add(self):
        x = self.a + self.b
        return x
    def Sub(self):
        y = self.a - self.b
        return y

class TASKS:
    def tsk1(self):           
        PrintObj1 = FUNC(10,20)
        print(PrintObj1.Add())
    def tsk2(self):
        PrintObj2 = FUNC(100,50)
        print(PrintObj2.Sub())

class RUNTASK:
    Obj = TASKS()
    Obj.tsk1()
    Obj.tsk2()
```

Comment: Looks absolutely fine,  You might have been after `Obj = TASKS` rather than `Obj = TASKS()` maybe?  You should not really use capitals as variables unless they are constants however.

Comment: `RUNTASK` looks like it should be a function, not a class.  What would it mean to have a `RUNTASK` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code looks correct, but you can also use `TASKS` class that contains only static methods. A static method is a method that belongs to a class rather than an instance of a class, so you don't need to create an instance of a class to invoke a static method (it's convenient in such cases):

```
class FUNC:

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def Add(self):
        x = self.a + self.b
        return x
    def Sub(self):
        y = self.a - self.b
        return y


class TASKS:

    @staticmethod
    def tsk1():
        PrintObj1 = FUNC(10,20)
        print(PrintObj1.Add())

    @staticmethod
    def tsk2():
        PrintObj2 = FUNC(100,50)
        print(PrintObj2.Sub())

TASKS.tsk1()
TASKS.tsk2()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing here is creating an **object** of another class, inside a method of a class.  If you wanted to show that the `FUNC` class belongs completely to `TASKS`, you could do this:

```
class TASKS:
    class FUNC:
        def __init__(self,a,b):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
        def Add(self):
            x = self.a + self.b
            return x
        def Sub(self):
            y = self.a - self.b
            return y

    @staticmethod
    def tsk1():
        PrintObj1 = TASKS.FUNC(10,20)
        print(PrintObj1.Add())

    def tsk2(self):
        PrintObj2 = self.FUNC(100,50)
        print(PrintObj2.Sub())


TASKS.tsk1()

obj = TASKS()
obj.tsk2()
```

This is called an *inner* or *nested* class.  It's not particularly common in Python.  In addition, I've shown the two ways of accessing the inner class, one using instance methods and one using static methods as suggested by @ArtsiomPraneuski (which seems more appropriate here.)